# What is the difference between properties `Name`, `Caption` and `DeviceID` (when executing `wmic LogicalDisk`)?

Tags: windows, command-line, logical-drive

When executing the command line `wmic LogicalDisk`, several properties of all logical disks of the computer system are returned. Three of them are `Name`, `Caption` and `DeviceID`, having the same value per drive, namely the drive letter `C:`, `D:`, etc.

What is the difference between these properties? Which one always returns the drive letter that I can access the respective drive with in the console `cmd`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
==> wmic logicaldisk get Caption, DeviceID, Name
Caption  DeviceID  Name
C:       C:        C:
D:       D:        D:
E:       E:        E:

==>
```

Pay your attention to each property **Qualifiers** in [Win32_LogicalDisk class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation:

**Caption**

- Data type: string
- Access type: Read-only
- Qualifiers: MaxLen (64), DisplayName ("Caption")
- Short description of the object—a one-line string.
  This property is inherited from CIM_ManagedSystemElement.

**DeviceID**

- Data type: string
- Access type: Read-only
- Qualifiers: **Key**, Override ("DeviceId"), MappingStrings ("WMI")
- Unique identifier of the logical disk from other devices on the system.
  This property is inherited from CIM_LogicalDevice.

**Name**

- Data type: string
- Access type: Read-only
- Qualifiers: DisplayName ("Name")
- Label by which the object is known. When subclassed, this property *can be overridden to be a **key** property*.
  This property is inherited from CIM_ManagedSystemElement.

[**Key** Qualifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392157(v=vs.85).aspx) is fundamental:

> The `Key` qualifier indicates whether the property is part of the
>   namespace handle.

Moreover, there is next important note inside [the former link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The [Get Disk info using wmi/cim... do it the right way](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Get-Disk-info-using-wmicim-ff0bd352) PowerShell
>   code example on the TechNet Gallery uses `Win32_LogicalDisk` to
>   retrieve `DeviceID`, `VolumeName`, and `Size` from a target device. In
>   particular, this sample includes rigorous exception handling, and
>   returns a single object per computer, rather than per disk.

Comment: So in short, I need to go for `DeviceID` if I want to use the returned drives in `cmd` (as per Windows default)?

Comment: @aschipfl yes, `DeviceID` would supply value appropriate for all purposes.